# add localtime to each frame as metadata or subtitle while streaming use ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, udp, pipe, metadata

I want to encode some raw frames as nvenc_h264 and then stream it over UDP. What I need, now, is to add some data like capturing time to each frame as its metadata or subtitle(just for that frame or specifying in the metadata that it is just related to which frame.).

now I use this command in C# to start FFmpeg for receiving raw frame using pipe and stream it over UDP.

```
          "-f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -pixel_format rgba"
          + " -colorspace bt709"
          + " -s " + width + "x" + height
          + " -framerate " + frameRate + " -vsync 0 "
          + " -loglevel warning -i - "// +// preset.GetOptions()
          + " -c:v h264_nvenc  -preset ll -zerolatency 1 -cq 10 -bf 2 -g 150 -f mpeg pipe:10" //udp://172.20.82.106:2000?"  //outputPath
```

The base code that I used is here:
https://github.com/keijiro/FFmpegOut

and I use this command for receiving and saving the file:
`ffmpeg -i udp://127.0.0.1:2001 -c:v h264_nvenc video.mp4`

As I said I want the times as data that I can process it later, not just like a watermark on the frame. How can I add it? is there any way?